# Logstash instance slave failover

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, master-slave, logstash-forwarder

Does someone knows how to scale Logstash? What do I mean by scaling? 
Let's say I have one instance of Logstash producing messages from jdbc to Kafka and lets say that node where Logstash service is installed and instance of him is running fall down suddenly.

How to continue with the same process, something like master-slave config? Is there any way to acomplish that or I need to set some work around by myself?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are sending your messages to logstash. Are you using filebeat? I know it has an option to configure more than 1 logstash instance to send to. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/config-filebeat-logstash.html) is the documentation for it.